# Excel Name minus field

Tags: excel, formulas

I want to use a formula to find if the name in the first field is the same to subtract first field E from last field F.

For example:

```
    A      B       C
1  John    1       2
2  John    2       3
3  John    3       3
4  Danny   1       4
```

I need the formula to find the first field with name John  and the last one and to subtract c4 from b1.

I hope you understand what i need

Comment: "...to subtract c4 from b1". Not sure I understand. Row 4 contains "Danny", not "John". Did you mean c3?

Answer (score 0):

You stated *'subtract c4 from b1'* but I'm not sure if that should be the other way around. In any event, this can be easily accomplished by using an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair first with an exact match and then with an approximate match.

However, this needs to be performed on **sorted data** in order to produce reliable results.

```
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(E3,A:A, 0))-INDEX(C:C, MATCH(E3,A:A ))
```

[image: sorted_match]

Note that the unsorted data has trouble returning an approximate match for *Danny* while the sorted data has no problem. The data can be sorted in an ascending or descending manner; see the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) for specifics on how to adjust the **[match_type]** parameter accordingly.